# Is it possible to check if mitm-certificate is installed in addon?

Tags: mitmproxy

I was wondering if it is possible to check if the MITM certificate is installed and if not then redirect the client to the `mitm.it` page.

I can't find anything in the documentation about this.

Comment: That depends on what URL the user has entered in the web browser. If it was an HTTPS URL no data is transmitted which of course also means that you can't inform the user or perform a redirect. As web browsers just switch to "https" first and most web sites also support https your idea will not work. Therefore from my perspective there is no other way than RTFM.

Comment: Thanks for the reply - So how I understand your comment - then MITMProxy is working only on the application layer and can therefore not intercept packages which are encrypted. So there is no way that I can use MITMProxy to check if the correct certificate is installed when someone tries to connect to anything on port 443 (or 80) - I know about some captive portals that do something like this - so maybe I just need to use a captive portal instead and not authorize internet access until the certificate is installed.

Comment: Captive portals also can only work if the requested URL is insecure http.